# The combination of Neo4j and Electron

Tags: neo4j, electron

I have data in Neo4j database, I want to create a graphical UI using [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) framework for the data stored in Neo4j, but I have no idea where to start. Is there any resource or reference about how to combine these two technologies?

Comment: I'd start by searching for NPM packages. A quick search revealed [this NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/neo4j) which will let you connect to a Neo4J database from Node.js and probably is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be similar to any time you'd want Electron to launch and communicate with some external process.

E.g.,

[Can Electron apps be integrated with java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45638644/can-electron-apps-be-integrated-with-java-code)

And once the neo4j process is launched, you can communicate with it via `neo4j-driver`:

https://neo4j.com/developer/javascript/